How do I resolve the anchor build error: Failed to obtain package metadata
I created a project with the command: anchor init solanasc and I receive this error when I run anchor build
ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `\\?\C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Rust_projects\solanasc\programs\*`
    
    Caused by:
      failed to read `\\?\C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Rust_projects\solanasc\programs\*\Cargo.toml`
    
    Caused by:
      The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)

I have tried the solutions here: `anchor build` fails with error, "failed to load manifest for workspace member", to no avail.
I am currently using Windows 10, and git bash. Here is my cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "solanasc"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "solanasc"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"


Can you try a normal cargo build-sbf from your program's directory? Since there's only one program, that might resolve the issue

I am having the same issue. Did you find the solution for this ?

I had the same problem, the error suggests that there is an invalid file path or character in the Cargo.toml file.
I resolve it in changing:
[workspace]
members = [
     "programs/*"
]
[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true

to
[workspace]
members = [
     "programs/my_program_name"
]
[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true

t's not exactly the same configuration as your project, but if it helps.
